# Type '() => Element' is not assignable to type 'string'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, function, react-props, dangerouslysetinnerhtml

Grettings !

I have a conventional `function` and I'm returning a `span` with a `prop`(if I'm not wrong).
On my ts code I have this error

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cczrk.png)

Here's my code.The file name is `qCard.tsx`

```
import { QuestionAnswerTwoTone } from "@material-ui/icons";
import React from "react";

// crear props
type Props = {
  question: string;
  answers: string[];
  callback: any;
  userAnswer: boolean;
  questionNm: number;
  totalQuestions: number;
};

// A function statement declared component that takes no children.
export default function QuestionCard({
  question,
  answers,
  callback,
  userAnswer,
  questionNm,
  totalQuestions,
}: Props) {
  //duda
  return (<div>
      <p> Question :  {questionNm} / {totalQuestions} </p>
      <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: question }} />
      <div>
          {answers.map(function answer(){
              return(  <div>
                <button disabled={userAnswer} onClick={callback}>
                    <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: answer }}/>
                </button>
            </div>);
          } )}
      </div>

  </div>
    
        );
}
```

*(Error line)*

I have tried to remove `{{ **__html**: answer }}` leaving it like : `{{  answer }}` but it doesn't work.

Comment: Hint: you've got both a parameter `answer` in your `QuestionCard` definition *and* a local function called `answer`. Maybe rename the second one (or don't name it at all).

Comment: Why your problem is `{{ **__html**: answer }}` but in your code, you are using `<p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: question }} />`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because, you are using the function name (an element in React) for __html:

```
answers.map(function answer(){
 //    __html: answer ^^
```

Use arrow function instead:

```
answers.map(answer => {
  // __html: answer // now it works.
```

Or, if you wish to continue using function statement then you can pass a parameter and use:

```
answers.map(function answer(ans){
  // __html: ans
```